# AdMob : How to query admob for my app earnings

Tags: service, web, admob

I've already configured adMob for my Android apps and have no problem with that.

Right now I'm looking for any way to check my apps earnings (if possible for each of the apps separately) in any given moment.

Somebody knows if there's any API, library or Web Service I can use to access my AdMob account and get info about my apps' statistics and so on ?

I've already checked the official APK but it seems only intended to show the ads in your app and nothing else.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I answer myself.

I was doing some research, and I found that after the recent changes on AdMob, and the migration to AdSense, you must use the AdSense API to get this info.

In particular, each Android app is associated with a "adunit" id, so if you want to check the info of any particular app you might use:

https://developers.google.com/adsense/management/v1.4/reference/accounts/reports/generate

with the following data:

```
accountId = your Publisher ID (pub-XXXXXXX)
startDate and endDate = The interval of dates you want to check
dimension = AD_UNIT_ID
metric = EARNINGS
```

With this query you'll have the required info, separated by App.

You get the results in JSON form.

Answer (score 0):

There is an [AdMob API](https://developers.google.com/admob/api/v1/getting-started) available to get the AdMob specific data.

It provides a possibility to generate [network](https://developers.google.com/admob/api/v1/reference/rest/v1/accounts.networkReport/generate) and [mediation](https://developers.google.com/admob/api/v1/reference/rest/v1/accounts.mediationReport/generate) reports available. It could be as simple as:

```
curl -X POST https://admob.googleapis.com/v1/accounts/<your_publisher_id>/mediationReport:generate \
       -H "Authorization: Bearer <access_token>" \
       -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
       --data @- << EOF
{
  "report_spec": {
    "date_range": {
      "start_date": {"year": 2020, "month": 4, "day": 1},
      "end_date": {"year": 2020, "month": 4, "day": 1}
    },
    "dimensions": ["AD_SOURCE", "AD_UNIT", "PLATFORM"],
    "metrics": ["ESTIMATED_EARNINGS"]
  }
}
EOF
```

- .net: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/apis/admob/v1
- java: https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-java-client-services/tree/master/clients/google-api-services-admob/v1

## Get an Oauth2.0 access token

### With oauth2l

install: https://github.com/google/oauth2l

```
oauth2l header --json <path_to_secret_json> https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admob.report
```

*path_to_secret_json* - is one from the credentials page on the google cloud console.

### With curl

Replace the *oauth2_client_id* with the one you have in your “Cloud project credentials - OAuth 2.0 client IDs” page. (https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials?project=)

https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?access_type=offline&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fadmob.report&response_type=code&client_id=&redirect_uri=urn%3Aietf%3Awg%3Aoauth%3A2.0%3Aoob

- Open this link in incognito browser mode;
- Follow the instruction, and accept the consonant screen with AdMob publisher's account;
- Copy the code, it would be needed for the following request:

```
curl -L \
-d "client_id=<oauth2_client_id>" \
-d "client_secret=<oauth2_secret>" \
-d "grant_type=authorization_code" \
-d "code=<sign_in_code_from_the_previous_step>" \
-d "redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob" \
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token
```

*oaut2_client_id* and *oauth2_secret* can be found on the OAuth 2.0 client Id page.

Response:

```
{
  "access_token": "<access_token>",
  "expires_in": 3600,
  "refresh_token": "<refresh_token>",
  "scope": "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admob.report",
  "token_type": "Bearer"
}
```